# How correctly include VueRouter in Laravel Project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-mix

I try to implement VueRouter in Laravel project but arreas error Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

app.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './components/App'
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent'
import ExampleComponent1 from './components/ExampleComponent1'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: ExampleComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/example',
            component: ExampleComponent1
        }
    ]
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: `<app></app>`,
    components: {
        App
    }
})
```

components/App.vue

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <router-link :to="'/'"></router-link>
            <router-link :to="'/example'"></router-link>
        </div>
        <div>
            <router-vue></router-vue>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

how can I connect correctly vue-router?

Comment: I inserted router after components:{App} in const app. and it's working)

Comment: Yep, that is your problem.  Alternatively, you can do this: `const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've misspelled `<router-view />` in `App.vue` which is probably causing the warning.

Comment: i changed, but nothing happened

Comment: Error is same: Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

Comment: Problem was resolved by inserting router after components